# Pandas - Date Add based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns 1 with random numbers. and other with dates.

Now i want to add those days to date columnto make new one.

my code is.

```
df['Weeks'] = df['Time1'] + pd.DateOffset(days=(pd.to_numeric(df['Description'] * 7)))
```

error i get

```
TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.
```

numbers in first column are decimals not round numbers
How to have this fixed?

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66IwI.png)

Comment: This question would benefit from adding a sample of your dataframe, and a sample of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issuse:

- `pd.to_numeric(df['Description'] * 7)` gives you an float but `pd.DateOffset` expects integers
- You cannot add pd.DateOffset to a column

#### Fix

(Not sure why you are multiplying it by 7)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time1': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=5, freq='T'), 
                    'Description': [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3] }) 
df['Time2'] = df['Time1'] + (df['Description'] * 7).astype(int).apply(pd.offsets.Day)

print (df)
```

Output:

```
                Time1  Description               Time2
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00          1.0 2020-01-08 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 00:01:00          1.5 2020-01-11 00:01:00
2 2020-01-01 00:02:00          2.0 2020-01-15 00:02:00
3 2020-01-01 00:03:00          2.5 2020-01-18 00:03:00
4 2020-01-01 00:04:00          3.0 2020-01-22 00:04:00
```

Comment: Thanks this helped alot to get that fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`new_day = (dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(days=2))`

instead of day=2 you can input the column and desired date instead of now.